# How one can draw 405 degree angle in learning material?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, metapost, asymptote

I would like to know how one can draw teaching material of trigonometry in LaTeX? Namely, I was looking how to draw 405 degree angle i.e. unit circle, a line segment to the circumference and a spiral from x-axis to the line segment that goes around the circle over once. Also, the spiral should end to a small arrow which shows that I meant 405 degree angle rather than -405 degree angle.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It's always good to supply a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to show what you have tried...perhaps in this case you have no idea:). See [spiral cone](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133183/draw-spiral-cone-tikz) and [3d sprial](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217508/reproducing-image-of-a-spiral-using-tikz) for possible ways of doing this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's how you can do this using PGFPlots:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis equal image,
            enlargelimits,
            xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
            data cs=polar,
            samples=100
        ]
            \addplot [thick, black, smooth, domain=0:360] {1};
            \addplot [thick, red, -latex, smooth, domain=0:405] {0.3+x/2000} node [pos=0.9, anchor=south west] {$405^\circ$};
            \addplot [thick, black] coordinates {(0,0) (405,1)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 21):

Here is a Tikz version without using `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3cm,y=3cm,axis/.style={-latex,very thin},thick]
\draw[axis] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[axis] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\draw (0,0) circle(0.8) -- (405:0.8);
\draw [red,->,domain=0:405,smooth,samples=100] 
    plot ({\x}: {0.3 + \x/3000}) node[right] {$405^\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendering]

Note that the node `pos` parameter does not work with tikz's `plot` command, so if you need positionning nodes on the path, it is better to use `pgfplots`.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a simple MetaPost solution.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
input TEX;
beginfig(1);

theta = 405;

path xx, yy, s, c;
xx = (left--right) scaled 5cm;
yy = (down--up)    scaled 5cm;
drawarrow xx withcolor .7 white;
drawarrow yy withcolor .7 white;

c = fullcircle scaled 8cm;
s = (1.2cm,0) for t=1 step 1 until theta-eps: -- (1.2cm + (t/500)*cm,0) rotated t endfor;

drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1);
linejoin := mitered;
draw c;
draw origin -- point theta/45 of c; 
drawarrow s withcolor .8 red; 
label.rt(TEX("$" & decimal theta & "^{\circ}$"), point .95 theta of s) withcolor .8 red;
endfig;
end.
```

Answer (score 8):

`Asymptote` version using `polargraph` to draw the Archimedean spiral:

```
// spiral.asy:
//
settings.tex="pdflatex";
size(5cm);
import graph;
import fontsize;
defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{siunitx}\usepackage{lmodern}");
pen linePen=darkblue+0.8bp;
pen thinPen=linewidth(0.7*linewidth())+gray(0.3);
real r=1, phi=405, rphi=radians(phi), d=0.2;
draw(Circle(0,r),linePen);
draw(E--(0,0)--rotate(phi)*E,linePen);
guide s=polargraph(new real(real t){return d*(1+t/rphi);},0,rphi);
draw(s,thinPen,Arrow(size=3));
label("$\ang{"+string(phi)+"}$",point(s,length(s)),E);
//
// to get spiral.pdf, run
// asy spiral.asy
//
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

With the `mfpic` package. To draw the spiral representing the angle, I used a simple polar function. Notice the `\trimpath{ , }` macro which trims the spiral at its extremities, to allow it not to overlap the x-axis and the radius at these points.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[metapost, mplabels]{mfpic}
    \mfpverbtex{%&latex
        \documentclass{scrartcl}
        \begin{document}}
    \setlength{\mfpicunit}{1cm}
    \opengraphsfile{\jobname}   
\begin{document}
    \begin{mfpic}[4]{-1.25}{1.25}{-1.25}{1.25}
        \doaxes{xy}
        \penwd{1.2bp}
        \circle{origin, 1}
        \lines{origin, \plr{(1, 405)}}
        \store{big_angle}\plrfcn{0, 405, 1}{.25 + .15/360 t}
        \arrow[cred]\draw[red]\trimpath{.5bp, 1.2bp}\mfobj{big_angle}
        \tlpointsep{3bp}
        \tlabelcolor{red}
        \tlabel[cl]{point 382.5 of big_angle}{$405^\circ$}
    \end{mfpic}
    \closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

To be processed with (PDF)LaTeX, then MetaPost, and then (PDF)LaTeX again.

[image]