# Arrows with curved line

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, arrows, tikz-arrows

I Need to reproduce a figure somewhat like the one here: [Drawing Angles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234169/22432)

The problem is that I get a figure wich differ from the original one: the arrow at the end of the spiral get vertical direction.

[image: Arrow at the end of a spiral]

What's wrong here.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis equal image,
            enlargelimits,
            xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
            data cs=polar,
            samples=100
        ]
            \addplot [thick, black, smooth, domain=0:360] {1};
            \addplot [thick, red, -latex, smooth, domain=0:405] {0.3+x/2000} node [pos=0.9, anchor=south west] {$405^\circ$};
            \addplot [thick, black] coordinates {(0,0) (405,1)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: We really cannot possibly say `what's wrong here` without seeing where here is. Please post your code in the form of a small, complete document we can compile to reproduce the problem with the arrow.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem using the code you've posted. What version of `pgfplots` do you have and which version of TikZ/PGF?

Comment: I'm using v2.10 for both.

Comment: Then please upgrade. Then it will work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved by updating TikZ and/or PGFPlots.