# How to make a spiral in coordinate system using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, pgfmath, coordinates

How do I generate a figure similar to this, but the value of 600° must be 1201°, and the spiral must take 3 revolutions (1201°/360°=3 revolutions).

[image: Figure from Trigonometry: A brief conversation]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!! Take a look at this post, it could be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234167/how-one-can-draw-405-degree-angle-in-learning-material

Comment: Thank you so much, @JuanCastaño.