# Drawing a DNA/SNP genome double helix in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to make this drawing in Ti*k*Z, but unfortunately I'm having a hard time getting started.

[image]

It seems there are no pre-packaged options available for this. A first attempt, based on code examples from TeX.SX is found below, but it lacks the 3D effect on the the Helix and the base pairs look rather simplistic

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3+[domain=0:4*pi, samples=100, samples y=0,no marks, smooth, draw=red](
  {x/(3*pi)},
  {cos(deg(x))},
  {sin(deg(x))}
 )   coordinate[pos=0.3]  (a1)  coordinate[pos=0.3]  (b1)  coordinate[pos=0.9]  (c1) ;
\addplot3+[domain=0:4*pi, samples=100, samples y=0,no marks, smooth, draw=green](
  {x/(3*pi)},
  {cos(deg(x+pi))},
  {sin(deg(x+pi))}
 )   coordinate[pos=0.3]  (a2) coordinate[pos=0.6]  (b2) coordinate[pos=0.9]  (c2) ;
\draw (a1)--(a2);
\draw (b1)--(b2);
\draw (c1)--(c2);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related, and a possible starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129860/helix-on-a-cylinder

Comment: With e.g. `tikz-3dplot` this can be done (I think) and is not even too difficult.

Comment: Another possible starting point: [Reproducing image of a spiral using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/217508/14500).

Answer (score 8):

This may be completely off (because I cannot judge from your screen shot what the 3d properties of your helix are), but maybe a start (and according to Wikipedia it may not be off). If you specify the 3d properties more I will be happy to adjust it, if necessary. Of course one can add the thingies with the letters, but again I don't know their orientation in 3d. So what I can offer with my current knowledge is

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tikzset{helix part/.style n args={2}{insert path={
plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=-90+#1*180:90+#1*180,
samples=11] ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*cos(\x)},
{\x*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}/360)+#2},{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*sin(\x)})
-- plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=90+#1*180:-90+#1*180,
samples=11] 
({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*cos(\x)},
{\x*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}/360)+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/width}+#2},{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*sin(\x)})
}},helix/.is family,
helix/.cd,
radius/.initial=3,stretch/.initial=3,width/.initial=1.5}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{105}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (\Length,0,0) node[below]{$x$};
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,\Length,0) node[left]{$y$};
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\Length) node[left]{$z$};
% \clip[tdplot_screen_coords] (0,-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}) 
rectangle (20,1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius});
\foreach \X in {0,2,...,8}
{
\path[top color=blue!60!black,bottom color=blue!30,middle color=blue,
helix part={\X}{0}]
;
\path[top color=red!60!black,bottom color=red!30,middle color=red,
helix part={\X}{0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}}] 
;
}
\foreach \X in {1,3,...,9}
{
\path[top color=blue!30,bottom color=blue!60!black,middle color=blue,
helix part={\X}{0}];
\path[top color=red!30,bottom color=red!60!black,middle color=red,
helix part={\X}{-0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}}];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since this is a 3d picture, you can play with the view angles (within limitations).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tikzset{helix part/.style n args={2}{insert path={
plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=-90+#1*180:90+#1*180,
samples=11] ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*cos(\x)},
{\x*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}/360)+#2},{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*sin(\x)})
-- plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=90+#1*180:-90+#1*180,
samples=11] 
({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*cos(\x)},
{\x*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}/360)+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/width}+#2},{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*sin(\x)})
}},helix/.is family,
helix/.cd,
radius/.initial=3,stretch/.initial=3,width/.initial=1.5}
\begin{document}
\foreach \Ang in {5,15,...,355}
{\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{120+30*sin(\Ang)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (\Length,0,0) node[below]{$x$};
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,\Length,0) node[left]{$y$};
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\Length) node[left]{$z$};
\clip[tdplot_screen_coords] (0,-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}) 
rectangle (20,1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius});
\foreach \X in {0,2,...,8}
{
\path[top color=blue!60!black,bottom color=blue!30,middle color=blue,
helix part={\X}{0}]
;
\path[top color=red!60!black,bottom color=red!30,middle color=red,
helix part={\X}{0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}}] 
;
}
\foreach \X in {1,3,...,9}
{
\path[top color=blue!30,bottom color=blue!60!black,middle color=blue,
helix part={\X}{0}];
\path[top color=red!30,bottom color=red!60!black,middle color=red,
helix part={\X}{-0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}}];
}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Barbara Beeton kindly informed me in the chat that the above [may be left-handed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49866566#49866566). Anyway, the handedness is a simple sign flip.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tikzset{helix part/.style n args={2}{insert path={
plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=-90+#1*180:90+#1*180,
samples=11] ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*cos(-\x)},
{\x*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}/360)+#2},{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*sin(-\x)})
-- plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=90+#1*180:-90+#1*180,
samples=11] 
({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*cos(-\x)},
{\x*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}/360)+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/width}+#2},{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*sin(-\x)})
}},helix/.is family,
helix/.cd,
radius/.initial=3,stretch/.initial=3,width/.initial=1.5}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{105}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\foreach \X in {0,2,...,8}
{\path[top color=blue!60!black,bottom color=blue!30,middle color=blue,
helix part={\X}{0}];
\path[top color=red!60!black,bottom color=red!30,middle color=red,
helix part={\X}{0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}}];}
\foreach \X in {1,3,...,9}
{\path[top color=blue!30,bottom color=blue!60!black,middle color=blue,
helix part={\X}{0}];
\path[top color=red!30,bottom color=red!60!black,middle color=red,
helix part={\X}{-0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}}];}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can definitely also build in base pairs. Of course, if you maintain 3d and orthographic projections, the code is not a one-liner. So I expect the <s>usual suspects</s> some other users to show up and say that one can use such a simple code instead, so I stop here.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tikzset{helix part/.style n args={2}{insert path={
plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=-90+#1*180:90+#1*180,
samples=11] ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*cos(-\x)},
{\x*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}/360)+#2},{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*sin(-\x)})
-- plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=90+#1*180:-90+#1*180,
samples=11] 
({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*cos(-\x)},
{\x*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}/360)+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/width}+#2},{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*sin(-\x)})
}},
helix coordinate/.style n args={2}{insert path={
({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*cos(-1*(#1))},
{((#1)/360)*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius})+#2},
{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*sin(-1*(#1))})}},
helix/.is family,
helix/.cd,
radius/.initial=3,stretch/.initial=3,width/.initial=1.5}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\newcounter{cup}
\newcounter{cdown}
\begin{document}
\foreach \Ang in {5,15,...,355}
{\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{120+30*sin(\Ang)}
\setcounter{cup}{0}
\setcounter{cdown}{0}
\def\LstUp{{"red","red","blue","green!70!black","yellow","blue"}}
\def\LstDown{{"yellow","blue","red","blue","green!70!black","red","blue"}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\clip[tdplot_screen_coords] (0,-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}) 
rectangle (20,1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius});
\foreach \X in {0,2,...,8}
{\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\path[top color=blue!60!black,bottom color=blue!30,middle color=blue,
helix part={\X}{0}];
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
\foreach \Y [count=\Z] in {-90}
{\path [helix coordinate={180*\X+\Y}{0}] coordinate(start1)
[helix coordinate={180*\X+\Y}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/width}}] coordinate(start2)
[helix coordinate={180*\X+\Y+180}{-0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}}]
coordinate(end1)
[helix coordinate={180*\X+\Y+180}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/width}-0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}}]
coordinate(end2); 
\stepcounter{cup}
\stepcounter{cdown}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cup}{\LstUp[mod(\number\value{cup},6)]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cdown}{\LstDown[mod(\number\value{cdown},7)]}
\ifnum\Z<2
\path (end1) -- (start1) coordinate[midway] (aux1)
(start2) -- (end2) coordinate[midway] (aux2);
\fill[\cup] (start2) -- (start1) -- (aux1) -- (aux2) -- cycle;
\fill[\cdown] (aux2) -- (aux1) -- (end1) -- (end2) -- cycle;
\else
\path (end1) -- (start2) coordinate[midway] (aux1)
(start1) -- (end2) coordinate[midway] (aux2);
\fill[\cup] (start2) -- (start1) -- (aux1) -- (aux2) -- cycle;
\fill[\cdown] (aux2) -- (aux1) -- (end1) -- (end2) -- cycle;
\fi}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\path[top color=red!60!black,bottom color=red!30,middle color=red,
helix part={\X}{0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}}];
\end{pgfonlayer}}
\foreach \X in {1,3,...,9}
{\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
\path[top color=blue!30,bottom color=blue!60!black,middle color=blue,
helix part={\X}{0}];
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
\foreach \Y [count=\Z] in {-90}
{\path [helix coordinate={180*\X+\Y}{0}] coordinate(start1)
[helix coordinate={180*\X+\Y}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/width}}] coordinate(start2)
[helix coordinate={180*\X+\Y+180}{-0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}}]
coordinate(end1)
[helix coordinate={180*\X+\Y+180}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/width}-0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}}]
coordinate(end2); 
\stepcounter{cup}
\stepcounter{cdown}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cup}{\LstUp[mod(\number\value{cup},6)]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cdown}{\LstDown[mod(\number\value{cdown},7)]}
\ifnum\Z<2
\path (end1) -- (start1) coordinate[midway] (aux1)
(start2) -- (end2) coordinate[midway] (aux2);
\fill[\cup] (start2) -- (start1) -- (aux1) -- (aux2) -- cycle;
\fill[\cdown] (aux2) -- (aux1) -- (end1) -- (end2) -- cycle;
\else
\path (end1) -- (start2) coordinate[midway] (aux1)
(start1) -- (end2) coordinate[midway] (aux2);
\fill[\cup] (start2) -- (start1) -- (aux1) -- (aux2) -- cycle;
\fill[\cdown] (aux2) -- (aux1) -- (end1) -- (end2) -- cycle;
\fi}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
\path[top color=red!30,bottom color=red!60!black,middle color=red,
helix part={\X}{-0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}}];
\end{pgfonlayer}}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]