# Is there any clash between tikz-3dplot and text part?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I'm here again. Here's the thing:

I found a large number of wonderful examples of TikZ-graph on [texexample.net](https://texample.net/). While I nothing relevant to protein except for [a DNA genome double helix in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482759/drawing-a-dna-snp-genome-double-helix-in-tikz). So I hope to modify it to a alpha helix like follows:

[image: All alpha helices protein]

And here are my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{helix part/.style n args={2}{insert path={
plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=-90+#1*180:90+#1*180,
samples=11] ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*cos(\x)},
{\x*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}/360)+#2},{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*sin(\x)})
-- plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=90+#1*180:-90+#1*180,
samples=11] 
({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*cos(\x)},
{\x*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}/360)+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/width}+#2},{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*sin(\x)})
}},helix/.is family,
helix/.cd,
radius/.initial=3,stretch/.initial=3,width/.initial=1.5}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{105}

\newcommand{\myprotein}[1]{%

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\begin{scope}[scale=.1]
rectangle (20,1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius});
\foreach \X in {0,2,...,8}
{
\path[top color=#1!60!black,bottom color=#1!30,middle color=#1,
helix part={\X}{0}];
}
\foreach \X in {1,3,...,9}
{
\path[top color=#1!30,bottom color=#1!60!black,middle color=#1,
helix part={\X}{0}];
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}


TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 

\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill (0,0) ellipse (2 and 1);

\myprotein{olive}

\end{tikzpicture}

TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
\end{document}
```

I found the structure was terrible just like this:

[image]

However, the structure returned to normal when I annotated the code `\myprotein{olive}` which was relevanted to tikz-3dplot.

[image]

So, I wonder is there any clash between tikz-3dplot and text part?

Comment: Your code nests `tikzpicture`s. Most likely this is the reason for your problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you nest `tikzpicture`s when you call `\myprotein`. Once you remove the `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}` you get

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{helix part/.style n args={2}{insert path={
plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=-90+#1*180:90+#1*180,
samples=11] ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*cos(\x)},
{\x*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}/360)+#2},{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*sin(\x)})
-- plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=90+#1*180:-90+#1*180,
samples=11] 
({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*cos(\x)},
{\x*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/stretch}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}/360)+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/width}+#2},{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius}*sin(\x)})
}},helix/.is family,
helix/.cd,
radius/.initial=3,stretch/.initial=3,width/.initial=1.5}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{105}

\newcommand{\myprotein}[2][]{%
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=.1,#1]
rectangle (20,1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/helix/radius});
\foreach \X in {0,2,...,8}
{
\path[top color=#2!60!black,bottom color=#2!30,middle color=#2,
helix part={\X}{0}];
}
\foreach \X in {1,3,...,9}
{
\path[top color=#2!30,bottom color=#2!60!black,middle color=#2,
helix part={\X}{0}];
}
\end{scope}}


TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 

\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill (0,0) ellipse (2 and 1);

\myprotein{olive}

\end{tikzpicture}

TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!